# spark code doesn't work on ec2's spark

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark, rdd

I am learning how to use spark and I program a piece of code like this:

```
object TestSpark {

  def main (args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val matrix = rddTypeChange(sc.textFile(args(0)))

    val order=matrix.map(s=>s.length).reduce(_+_)
    println(order)
  }

  def typeChange(str:Array[String]):Array[Double]={
    val array:Array[Double]=new Array(str.length)
    for(i<-0 until str.length)
      array(i)=str(i).toDouble
    array
  }

  def rddTypeChange(rdd:RDD[String]):RDD[Array[Double]]={
    rdd.map(data=>typeChange(data.split("\t")))
  }
}
```

I have a file named matrix.txt like this:

1 2

3 4

and the arg(0) is matrix.txt

The result will be 4(print) and when I run this in my IDE(idea)it works.But if I export a jar and run the jar on ec2,it doesn't work. On ec2,the matrix.txt is on hdfs.

why?

Comment: Please paste the stack trace in your question.

Comment: how to get the stack trace?